# gfsh echo --string=${SYS_USER} couldn't obtain the current value of the existing variable

Tags: geode

[Useful gfsh Shell Variables](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/16/tools_modules/gfsh/useful_gfsh_shell_variables.html) says `gfsh>echo --string=${VARIABLE}` could obtain the current value of the existing variable. But in my environment it **couldn't**.
e.g.:
`echo --string=${SYS_USER}` displayed `${SYS_USER}`

`gfsh>echo --string=$*` **could** display a list of all gfsh shell variables and their current values in my environment(Apache Geode 1.5.0).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with Geode 1.6 and GemFire 9.x (multiple versions). [EchoCommand.java](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/78dcf4b8fa86543e882365e78f1c8e2a623bffde/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/EchoCommand.java) has $* coded as a special case, but does not cover the other cases. I submitted JIRA [GEODE-5531](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-5531).